# Lossless HEIC images

Tags: graphics, image-editing, heic

I googled whether HEIC images are lossless or lossy, and whereas some articles and forum threads insist HEIC images are lossy, other insist that HEIC supports both lossy and lossless compression, but don't provide any details about how to use the latter. I use the latest Ventura, and when I edit HEIC images in Preview (and even if I chose "Lossless" when saving),

[image]

their quality degrade. So how to create HEIC images that won't degrade when I edit them?

Comment: HEIC (like JPEG) is a mathematical approximation of the original image. If you need pixel-level accuracy, use TIFF or similar.

Comment: @nohillside TIFF can have lossy compression, in fact, [it can use JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Part_2:_TIFF_Extensions). [JPEG can be lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG). Don't get compression and container formats mixed up.

Comment: @user71659 Indeed it does, but AFAIK Preview doesn't use lossy compression when storing as TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

The HEIC images you are editing are very likely already compressed. The original information has already been lost. There is no way to get it back.

What you seem to look after is a way to prevent them from being further compressed after edition, not lossless.

Generally, it is not a good idea to edit jpeg/heic images if you want optimal quality. Compression algorithms are not made to hide your editions, and they will often appear, and result in what you call image degradation.

You should use the original lossless information if available (e.g RAW for cameras)